# Swift : setup a Pan Gesture left to right

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I would like to set a Pan Gesture and assign it to a view, to make it moving only to the right and to the left according to the movement of the finger with a dynamic animation. 
I don't know how to do that because I'm beginning, thanks a lot !

Comment: This isn't so much a Swift question as it is one about UIKit. You can check out Apple's documentation on Gesture Recognizers here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

Comment: Do you have code for moving in all directions?

Comment: I'm sorry alexpls, I don't know how to use it, I'm really beginning

Comment: Jakub : I don't have the code

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Checking a PanGesture direction in swift could look like something like this.

```swift
extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    func isLeft(theViewYouArePassing: UIView) -> Bool {
        let detectionLimit: CGFloat = 50
        var velocity : CGPoint = velocityInView(theViewYouArePassing)
        if velocity.x > detectionLimit {
            print("Gesture went right") 
            return false
        } else if velocity.x < -detectionLimit {
            print("Gesture went left")
            return true
        }
    }
}

// Then you would call it the way you call extensions
var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer

// and pass the view you are doing the gesture on
panGesture.isLeft(view) // returns true or false
```

You could also create such a method without extensions as well, but I think this way is really nice.

Hope this helps anyone trying to find an answer to this!!